# How to provide BLoCs close to widgets without making them global in Flutter with named routes?

Tags: flutter, architecture, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm working with the BLoC pattern (flutter_bloc) in Flutter and I've come across a design challenge. I understand that it's recommended to provide BLoCs as closely as possible to where they're used to avoid unnecessary global state. It makes sense when placing BlocBuilderwidgets down the widget tree, but I'm struggling with the placement of **BlocProvider**'s.

In scenarios where a BLoC is shared between two or more pages, I find it hard to locate the BlocProvider without making it nearly global. For instance, in my current app structure, I'm using named routes. This leads to a structure where all pages only share one common ancestor page. If I provide the BlocProvider there, in the main.dart, **it essentially becomes global**. On the other hand, if I use the same BLoC for two distinct pages, I'm unsure where to put the BlocProvider.

Is there a recommended way to provide BLoCs for multiple pages without resorting to a global setup when using named routes in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following template basically for routing. And I can manage easily bloc providers for per page of the application.

app_route.dart:

```
abstract class AppRoute {
  static final MainBloc mainBloc = MainBloc();
  static Route onRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch(settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: () {
            return MultiBlocProvider(
              providers: [
                BlocProvider.value(value: mainBloc),
                ...
              ],
              child: PageHome(),
            );
          },
        );
      case 'routeName':
        return ...;
      default:
        throw 'undefined route';
    }
  }
}
```

main.dart:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    ...,
    onGenerateRoute: AppRoute.onRoute,
  );
}
```

for navigate:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'routeName');
```